# Electron win.setMaximizable(true) not working

Tags: electron

I am working on an electron where i allow user to enable or disable window full screen. I am using

```
win.setMaximizable(boolean)
```

but it throws this error popup

```
win.setMaximizable is not a function.
```

I have no idea why this error is coming although win object is defined. Or is there any way to set window property from a render process. Help is required.

Comment: When trying to set a property form the renderer process, try `remote`, as [documented here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/remote/). It will return the current `BrowserWindow` when used with `remote.getCurrentWindow();`. Are you using the current Electron version?

Comment: right now the issue is coming in the main process. My window is already initialised and on user interaction i want to disable the window fullscreen

this is not working


        win.setMaximizable(false);

but this is working fine

        win.setResizable(false);

Comment: On which platform are you developing? Also had some issues with that on Linux.

Comment: I am developing in mac. Once I upgraded electron this works fine. I used 

    win.setMaximizable(false);

it works.